# BackgroundImage() in Xamarin for cross platform mobile design not working

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Systems: Windows 10, Visual Studios, Xamarin, Cross platform Mobile Design, Xamarin Live app on iPhone X.

Inside of my MainPage.xaml file, I added the following code:

`BackgroundImage="Users\Zakariah Siyaji\Desktop\3840X2160-HDR-Wallpaper-1.jpg"`

Without this line, my code compiles and runs correctly. With this line of code, I do not receive errors; in fact, the output window displays: "Deploy to iPhone Player succeeded." But, the Xamarin Live App crashes on the iPhone X. I am having trouble displaying a background image to my carousel page. Is there a fix that I am missing? Do I need additional code?

Comment: You are pointing to an image that exists on your desktop file system, which your "phone" does not have access to.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot access your local pc files from mobile phone,
if you need a background image, then Add it to drawable for android and for ios add it to assets folder under Resources folder.
later you can access it by using

```
BackgroundImage="image.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your phone cannot access your computer file system.